A question about integral and differential equations
I want to use Mathematica to reproduce the result of Eq.(16) under the Case I in the section 2.1 of this Article, but I failed. The result of Eq.(16) is based on differential equation Eq.(14), where, the metric function $f(r)$ can be defined by the following expression: $f(r)=e^{N(r)} \Rightarrow ln(f(r))=N(r) \Rightarrow N'(r)=f'(r)/f(r)$. Therefore, under the case of $P(r)=0$ in section 2.1, Eq.(14) in Mathematica reads
f'[r]/f[r]==(2 M[r])/(r (r - 2 M[r])),

where, $M(r)$ is given by Eq.(5),
Msp[r_] = 
  4 Pi  Integrate[\[Rho][r]*r^2, {r, rb, r}, 
       Assumptions -> {Rsp > r > rb, rb > 0}] // Simplify // Expand //
    Normal;
M[r_] = Mbh + Msp[r];

where, density function $\rho(r)$ reads
\[Rho][r_] = \[Rho]sp*(Rsp/r)^\[Gamma]sp;

And the initial condition of ODE Eq.(14) is Eq.(12),
f[rb] == 1 - 2 Mbh/rb,

Using the ODE and initial condition, in principle, the metric function $f(r)$ can be solved, but I failed. My attempt of the Mathematica code is as follows:
Clear["`*"]
$Assumptions = {{rb, Rsp, \[Gamma]sp, \[Rho]sp} \[Element] Reals && 
    Rsp > r > rb};
\[Rho][r_] = \[Rho]sp*(Rsp/r)^\[Gamma]sp;
Msp[r_] = 
  4 Pi  Integrate[\[Rho][r]*r^2, {r, rb, r}, 
       Assumptions -> {Rsp > r > rb, rb > 0}] // Simplify // Expand //
    Normal;
M[r_] = Mbh + Msp[r];
solfr = DSolve[{f'[r]/f[r] == (2 M[r])/(r (r - 2 M[r])), 
    f[rb] == 1 - 2 Mbh/rb}, f[r], r] // Simplify   (*ODE method*)
int = Integrate[(2 M[r])/(r (r - 2 M[r])), r] // Simplify // 
   Normal;(* Integrate method*)
solfr1 = int // Exp // Simplify

Follow the tips in the section 2.1, they solve the metric function $f(r)$ by approximating the integral in leading order of $\rho_{sp}$, which is valid for $rb \leq r \leq Rsp$. But I don't understand their approach and how to achieve their results. Therefore, here I am asking you all for help. Any approximate or analytical solution is acceptable. I would be grateful if you could help to achieve their results.
Thanks again for all your help!
